# One example involves manipulation of select statement in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

(SQL rookie question) I'm Working on a query which could find all the Worker who create products that include all the products created by Worker with id = 18.

```
CREATE TABLE Creates(
        ID CHAR(10),
        PRODUCTID CHAR(10),
        PRIMARY KEY (ID, PRODUCTID),
        FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Worker(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    };

CREATE TABLE Worker(
        ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    };
```

Here are what have in my table Creates now:

```
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('2', 'S100');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('2', 'D111');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('4', 'D111');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('4', 'S119');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('6', 'S2');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('6', 'D231');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('8', 'S103');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('10', 'S109');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('12', 'S189');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('14', 'S982');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('20', 'E341');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('22', 'E100');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('18', 'D111');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('18', 'D231');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('2', 'D231');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('24', 'D111');
INSERT INTO Creates VALUES('24', 'D231');
```

As we can see, actually the correct output should be ID 2 and 24.

This what I have now to make it true, but I don't think this correct, so I would like to hear from anyone or any suggestion that can help me with it, thank you in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
    FROM Creates 
    WHERE PRODUCTID = ALL (SELECT PRODUCTID FROM Creates WHERE ID = '18')
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

；

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Creates 
     WHERE PRODUCTID IN (SELECT PRODUCTID FROM Creates WHERE ID = '18') 
       AND (ID <> '18')
    ) AS t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Creates WHERE ID = '18')
```

returns

```
2
24
```

As you can see, the `Worker` table is not involved at all.  
The results are retrieved from `Creates` table by selecting the ids of the workers that have produced products that the worker with id `'18'` only if their number is equal to the number of the products that the worker with id `'18'` has produced.

Comment: This is a good approach. It is easy to read and it avoids the expensive cross join typically found in "Relational division".

Answer (score 0):

First you need a list of all products created by worker 18

```
SELECT product_id FROM Creates WHERE ID = '18'
```

Then you need a list of all employees

```
SELECT ID as worker_id FROM Workers WHERE ID <> '18'
```

Now you create a cartesian product of both results to have a list of all possible combinations

```
WITH products as (
  SELECT product_id FROM Creates WHERE ID = '18'
), employees as (
  SELECT ID as worker_id FROM Workers WHERE ID <> '18'
)
SELECT product_id, worker_id
FROM products
CROSS JOIN employees
```

Now you have to find if an employees have every product so you check with the Creates Table

```
WITH products as (
  SELECT product_id FROM Creates WHERE ID = '18'
), employees as (
  SELECT ID as worker_id FROM Workers WHERE ID <> '18'
), allMatches as (
  SELECT product_id, worker_id
  FROM products
  CROSS JOIN employees
)
SELECT A.worker_id
FROM allMatches A
LEFT JOIN Creates C
  ON A.product_id = C.product_id
 AND A.worker_id = C.worker_id
GROUP BY A.worker_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(C.product_id)
```

if a worker doesnt create a product the `LEFT JOIN` will create NULL on the match. And `COUNT(C.product_id)` doesnt count nulls

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method uses `listagg()`:

```
select c.id,
       listagg(c.productid, ',') within group (order by c.productid) as products
from creates c join
     creates c18
     on c18.productid = c.productid and
        c18.id = 18 and
        c.id <> 18 
group by c.id
having products = (select listagg(c.productid, ',') within group (order by c.productid) as products
                   from creates c
                   where c.id = 18
                  );
```

Comment: Interesting aproach. But who is c18p? and if is a typo  how the alias become c18

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . That should just be a reference to `products`.